# How to make a GridView of ListViews with dynamic size

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

Generally I am trying to re-produce this layout:
[image: iOS SS]

The idea is that you have the parent category (the top item in each list) and then the list of it's children categories. I get this info from a server so I can't hardcore anything. None of the layout is modified in code and currently I'm just trying to get the layout to work and then I'll wire it up to the actual data.
fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.<redacted>.app.EditCategoriesActivity.EditCategoriesFragment">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/edit_categories_list_width"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_grid"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GridView item view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border_box"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Cat"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_grid_item_parent_name"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_grid_item_parent_switch"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:layout_below="@id/edit_categories_grid_item_parent_name"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_grid_item_list"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Child"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_list_item_title"/>
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
    android:id="@+id/edit_categories_list_item_switch"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently it looks like this:
[image: Current Android]

The structure of the test data is:

> Test1>
>
> Test Child Cat
>
> Test Child Cat 2

-

> Test2>
>
> TestChild Cat -2
>
> TestChild Cat 2 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 3 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 4 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 5 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 6 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 7 -2
>
> TestChild Cat 8 -2

-
Also the listviews are VERY hard to scroll... by that I mean I've tried to scroll them all over the "hit area" well over a hundred times in my testing and only gotten 1 (the Test2 one if it matters) to scroll once... yeah...

Ideally all list items would be shown and there would be no scrolling in the gridview items, just the gridview itself.

Please let me know if there is any info I can give that you think will help. Like I said I'm basically just tying data to views in the code and that's it so I can see how that would affect the layout... you know besides the structure of the data itself. >.>

Anyways, Thanks for your time!

Comment: Nested scrolling Views don't work well, if at all, in Android. You probably want to use a GridLayout instead of a GridView.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Going to give it a try now!

Comment: Upon researching it a bit... I don't think GridLayout works like that. It's for laying things out in a grid pattern, but gridview manages/lays out subviews and recycles them. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Ok, I think I misinterpreted your post, and I'm not sure what you mean by "there would be no works about scrolling in the gridview items, just the gridview itself", but if you want the entire layout to scroll, go ahead and use the GridView, but don't use ListViews for the child Views.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, corrected now. It's very late here^^; So to be clear you suggest using the `GridView` and then just constructing the lists from scratch with a `LinearLayout`, maybe?

Comment: Yep. It'll be a little more work than using ListViews, but you won't have the scrolling issues.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad to hear that, but I don't deserve any rep just for helping with a vague outline. You did all the heavy lifting! I would ask, though, that you post and accept an answer, when you can, so that this question doesn't continue to appear as unanswered. You won't get any points from yourself, but give us a good explanation (and maybe a snippet or two, if necessary), and you'll get an upvote from me! Thanks. I appreciate the offer.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help either way! I'll post a detail answer as soon as I have the time^^;

Comment: Sorry mid-project and I have also run into another issue with it, but I'll post the answer when I get it fixed/finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it almost exactly how I envisioned it!

My first try at changes was to remove the listviews and replace them with `LinearLayouts` with a vertical orientation and then just loop over the data to fill it and inflate all the views for the data. This kinda worked, but the "cells" of the `GridView` would overlap each other and would re-position when you scrolled... needless to say this isn't ideal.

So then I looked at `GridLayout` again and decided to try filling it basically the same way I do the `LinearLayouts` and it worked almost perfectly! Threw it in a `ScrollView` and it was working! Now the cells don't arrange exactly how I would like them and I have to have multiple layout files for the different devices because it doesn't have an `auto-fit` option for columns, but overall I'm quite pleased with the results! Also, the other obvious draw back is that it's not getting recycled anymore, but I knew I wasn't going to have a ton of data and there were 0 images loading so I was lucky in that I didn't HAVE to have it. Hope this helps others!

P.S. Once RecycleView is fully released and stable it may be the way to go so if you haven't looked at that yet, DO! ^_^